# Find the area of the convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

So i have $ABCD$ is a convex quadrlateral and $E$ is the intersection point of diagonals. Given that $AE=2,BE= 5, CE = 6, DE =10$ and side $BC = 5$. I know the formula $A=\frac{1}{2}d_1 d_2 \sin \theta$ but I don't have the angle and there is no figure so Im not able to find the sides I was thinking to get all the sides and just use herons formula, but since I don't know if the intersections are right triangles I can't solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can fill out the angles of triangle $BEC$ with the law of cosines, right?  And then have angle $BEC$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $BC^2 = BE^2+EC^2-2\cdot BE\cdot EC\cos \angle BEC\Rightarrow 5^2=5^2+6^2 - 2\cdot 5\cdot 6\cos \angle BEC$

Comment: by cosine law, 53 degrees and $A=\frac{1}{2}(15)(8)sin53$ so area is 47.92?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother with exact value of the angle. Since — see above — $\cos\angle BEC = 3/5$ then $\sin\angle BEC = 4/5$ and thus area equals $AC\cdot BD\cdot\sin\angle BEC/2 = 8\cdot 15 \cdot (3/5)/2 = 36$